# A suitable constructor for type 'ApplicationInventory.Services.ServerInventoryService' could not be located

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, interface, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to create a service that is accessible by both Controllers and regular functions for all API calls to a specific endpoint for my ASP.Net Core 2.2 application. Whenever I try and inject the HttpClient class an error occurs before the functions can be reached/

I have setup my startup.cs as shown in documentation and have reduced the constructor inputs to just HttpClient so I know that's where the root of the issue is. I have added the HttpClient to the configure services section fo the Startup.cs class every way I can think of.

Startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            ...
                        // adding ability to make basic http calls 
            services.AddHttpClient<IServerInventoryService, ServerInventoryService>(c =>
            {
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://serverinventory.cooperatorsgroup.ca/api/");
            }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
            {
                return new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true
                };
            });

}
```

Controller:

```
       private ILogger<ServerInventoryApiController> logger;
        private IHttpClientFactory clientFactory;
        private readonly IServerInventoryService ServerInventoryService;
        public ServerInventoryApiController(ILogger<ServerInventoryApiController> _logger, IServerInventoryService _service, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            ServerInventoryService = _service;
            logger = _logger;
            clientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }
```

APIService:

```
  public class ServerInventoryService : IServerInventoryService
    {
        private HttpClient client;
        //        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public ServerInventoryService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            client = httpClient;
        }
```

Everytime a call is made to the Service result is:

"InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'ApplicationInventory.Services.ServerInventoryService' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor."

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? Fail to reproduce your issue with current code.

Comment: Unfortunately not, i can provide more code but this is what seemed relevant to the situation

Comment: If the code could not reproduce your issue, it is helpless, you could check whether this issue could be produced with your current code with a new .net core project.

Comment: Hi, @Grady Van Pinxteren did you find the problem of this issue?

Comment: Hey Yes, i believe the issue was with another section of code.