# .net core AddHttpClient with reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, httpclient

I'm using .net core 3.1 and I want to register my services with reflection.

My CustomProvider class:

```
public class CustomProvider : BaseProvider, ICustomProvider
{
public CustomProvider(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
            : base(httpClientFactory)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        }
}
```

It's run in the startup and registered successfully.

```
foreach (var type in assembly.ExportedTypes)
{
var interfaceType = type.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.GetInterfaces().Any(x => .Name.Contains("IProvider")));

if (interfaceType == null)
continue;

services.AddTransient(interfaceType, type);
}
```

After that, I'm registering specific of registred interface with HttpClient and Custom Handler.

```
services.Configure<ProxyOptions>(options => Configuration.GetSection("ProxyList").Bind(options));
services.AddTransient<ProxyHttpHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient<ICustomProvider>().ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler<ProxyHttpHandler>();
```

After sending the request I give an error:

> A suitable constructor for type 'ICustomProvider' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered
>   for all parameters of a public constructor.

I don't know why this exception fired. my contractor in CusotmerProvider is public.

I found another question about my link, It exception is exactlly my problem.
[A suitable constructor for type 'ApplicationInventory.Services.ServerInventoryService' could not be located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56907365/a-suitable-constructor-for-type-applicationinventory-services-serverinventoryse)

Comment: I suspect that `ICustomProvider` is returned by the `assembly.ExportedTypes` collection, and therefore you end up calling both `services.AddTransient(ICustomProvider, CustomProvider)` and `services.AddTransient(ICustomProvider, ICustomProvider)`. Which will cause the error you're seeing if it's happening in that order. Make sure that `assembly.ExportedTypes` returns only concrete types

Comment: @KevinGosse I'm sure the assembly.ExportedTypes just return only concrete types.

Comment: @SaeidMirzaei The error message shows that `ICustomProvider` was added as an implementation (as implied in @KevinGosse's comment) debug and recheck your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the Concrete instance of "HttpClient" via the constructor when using .AddHttpClient() via Dependency Injection so your implementation should be

```
CustomProvider(HttpClient client)
{
  _httpClient = client;

}
```

Note: If you want to use IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient() to instantiate your HttpClient instances then you do not need to add .AddHttpClient() in your Interface->class mapping registration you can simply inject it normally AsTransient or Scoped.

You can also call AddHttpClient in the services directly instead of per mapping.

```
services.AddHttpClient(instancename);
```

You can now use the IHttpClientFactory.CreateCllient(instancename) to create the concrete instance for you in calling code.